# Trying to Remove Duplicates based on first column

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to remove rows from column A to column V based on duplicates found in column A.

my current formula is:

```
Workbooks(TgtWB).ActiveSheet.Range("A15:V500").RemoveDuplicates _
    Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
```

My header is located on row 15.

the error i am getting is

> Application-defined or object-defined error

I have tried switching `ActiveSheet` with `worksheet("xxx")` but still doesn't seem to work either. i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Is your `TgtWB` open? You should ensure that the workbook is open first.

Comment: If TgtWB is open, it may or may not contain the ActiveSheet. Each open workbook does not have an ActiveSheet. There is only one ActiveSheet for the application instance. ActiveSheets is not a property of the Workbooks collection.

Answer (score 2):

Try (note worksheet**S**, not worksheet),

```
Workbooks(TgtWB).worksheetS("xxx").Range("A15:V500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
'or,
ActiveSheet.Range("A15:V500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

If TgtWB is open, it may or may not contain the ActiveSheet. Each open workbook does not have an ActiveSheet. There is only one ActiveSheet for the application instance. ActiveSheet is not a property of the Workbooks collection.

Answer (score 0):

Using built in functionality is great, unless you're a beginner like myself and the `.Applications` and `.Worksheets` get overwhelming and confusing. For a small data set, such as columns A through V (depending obviously on how many rows you have), a loop and if-statement not only can work well, but can be good practice as well! Something like this may work well:

```
Dim CurrentValue, LastValue As Variant
   LastValue = ""
   For I = 1 To 500
       CurrentValue = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & i).Value
       If CurrentValue = LastValue Then
           Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A" & i & ":V" & i).Clear Contents
       Else
           LastValue = CurrentValue
       End If
   Next i
```

This will loop through every row, ask if the current value in the cell is the same as the one previously observed (except the first one, the first one will automatically be saved by nature), and if it has been, it will clear the contents of the row. If it's not the same, it will assign it to the new variable and begin looking for new ones.

There are two drawbacks with this method that can be solved by simply adapting the code to your needs:

1. **Non-Sequential Items:** If the values that are duplicates are not sequential, the code won't kick them out. At that point I recommend using an application code or a dictionary. Dictionaries are infinitely useful for storing unique data entries and skipping duplicates.
2. **Deleting Rows:** When you delete rows in a loop it messes up your loop, throwing off the order of your incrementer. The best way to combat this is by first clearing the columns then having your code loop for empty rows and delete them *outside* of your loop.

This is very basic but something I've found greatly helpful as a beginner and hopefully other beginners and yourself can learn something from it.

**Happy Coding!**